# How to use Beyond Compare 4 on ubuntu using wine HQ?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wine, beyondcompare4

I'm using `Beyond Compare 4` on `Ubuntu 15.04` using `wine HQ` when i open a folder in it says `folder not found` but folder is present. I'm all the permission to folder.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem running Beyond Compare Version 4.1 beta (build 20431) using WineHQ in Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. Both the system and the installed copy of BC are 64-bit. [And you don't have to worry about the license agreement](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?14382-Is-running-Beyond-Compare-through-Wine-in-Linux-legal). FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare 4 for Windows is not supported on Linux using Wine. Use the Linux version of Beyond Compare instead of running the Windows version using Wine.

Download page for Beyond Compare 4:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php

Beyond Compare 4 Linux installation instructions:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_linux_install